# What is the difference (if any) between "fourier transform" and "SO(3) fourier transform"?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

What is the difference (if any) between "fourier transform" and "SO(3) fourier transform"?

I searched on Google but couldn't find a satisfiable answer.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual (discrete) Fourier transform expands a function in the basis set $e^{i n\phi}$, $\phi\in(0,2\pi)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The $\text{SO}(3)$ Fourier transform uses as basis the [Wigner D-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) $D_{\ell}^{m,n}$, which are an orthogonal basis for the rotation group,
$$f=\sum_{\ell=1}^L\sum_{m,n=-\ell}^\ell f_{\ell,m,n}D_\ell^{m,n}.$$
The integer $L$ is the degree of the transform. It is possible to rewrite this as a usual Fourier transform by expanding the Wigner-D function into a Fourier sum and then one can apply the Fast Fourier Transform algorithm, see [A Fast Fourier Algorithm on the Rotation Group](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.122.6676&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The complexity of this operation scales as $L^3\log L$.

This is an example of [noncommutative harmonic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_harmonic_analysis).

Comment: Why the scaling is not $\mathcal{O}(\log(L)L^3)$?

Comment: indeed it does, corrected --- thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Carlo Beenakker stated, you can find a detailed introduction to Fourier Transforms, Spherical Harmonics and Wigner-D matrices in [Chapter 3 of a 2017 PhD thesis at Bielefeld University linked here](https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/download/2913219/2913220/diss_ddiffert.pdf).

It focuses on applications for visual robot navigation (and therefore especially on real-valued implementations), but a brief summary of the general idea is given. For a purely math based focus, you can check the references.